# SWIG Unsatisfied Link Error in a different project

Tags: swig, shared, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have a portion of the project that requires me to wrap some existing C++ code. I made a test project for the wrapped code, and the test project is working.

However when I try to integrate this test project back into the main project. The following error takes place.

I am able to load the shared library, but as soon as I can run my first wrapped function, it breaks stating an unsatisfied link error.

Then I decided to not integrate my test project into my main project, but just directly copy my test project into the main project's environment and run it (meaning that it's the exact same code). And the same error happens.

I suspect from that, that I have a project setting error, but I'm not sure what project setting that would be, as I didn't do anything particularly special in project setting or run configurationw when I did my test project.

Cheers,

Jack

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it didn't work when I placed in a different project, is the match in the new project doesn't match the package name I assigned it when I generated it.

When generating wrapper files, it is very important to ensure that whatever package you assign to your wrapper files, that has to be the location where you place in your wrapper file (particularly the JNI file) in the project.

For example. If I set the package to be "swig", and I place in the project such that "level1.level2.level3.swig", this will stop working.